# parse json array in postgresql 9.3

Tags: json, postgresql-9.3

I want to write a function that takes a json array as input parameter and then to parse the array and store each json element in a text variable to use later.
I am using Postgres 9.3 and using `json_array_elements()` to help but cant go further.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Postgres 9.3 is no longer supported, you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes , I update to 9.6.12_1